# Mix two foreach. Notifications. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code here:

```
    $likes = Like::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
    $comments = Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

HTML:

```
@foreach($likes as $like)

@endforeach
```

How to implement `comments` foreach in the `likes` foreach so the output not appears like this: At first appears `likes` and then appears `comments`. I want to mix it so it could appear something like this:

Like Comment Like Comment Comment Like

It's like notifications going

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-merge) the collections, then [order them](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-sortbydesc) by `created_at`, then foreach on the new colleciton:

PHP:

```
$likes = Like::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
$comments = Comment::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

$notifications = $likes->merge($comments)->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

HTML:

```
@foreach($notifications as $notification)

@endforeach
```

Comment: And then how should I access `$like->user->image` or `$comment->user->name` ?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I think you should still be able to use those as you are now. The objects should still be present so you can still call functions on them.

Comment: I get `Undefined variable: like`

Comment: Ah, you'd need to try `$notification->user->image` etc

Comment: Okay now it shows the likes. How to access `comments` ?

Comment: They should all be wrapped in together. What part of a comment are you trying to get?

Comment: I think now the easiest way is to create new DB table and just store all this data there maybe and then just sort it by created_at

Comment: I want to show specifically: 'likes', 'comments'. They're seperate tables

Comment: I want to get it like this: `This user liked this post`, `This user commented on this post`

Comment: Everything works. Just played a bit with HTML. Big thanks!

Comment: I think ideally you should probably look into [polymorphism](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations). You can create a "notification" table that will pull all your likes and comments for you, which would probably make this a little easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't.

Instead of using a foreach for both, you can consider using a key for comment.

Something like this would do I think:

```
foreach($likes as $key => $like) {
   print $like
   print $comment[$key];
}
```

As a side note: I do not have any experience with Laravel.